# Converting a BGR bitmap to RGB

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I am getting bitmaps from a buffer from a net cam.  When I assign these to a PictureBox the red and blue are reversed.

What can I do to the bitmap or to the PictureBox to get the red and blue in their proper places?

Comment: Some problems with camera?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the camera. It's BGR color space. Mostly to do with endianness. Annoying, though, since you usually have to do extra work to get things to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code does the needed conversion:

```
public static void RGBtoBGR(Bitmap bmp)
{
    BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                                   ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);

    int length = Math.Abs(data.Stride) * bmp.Height;

    unsafe
    {
        byte* rgbValues = (byte*)data.Scan0.ToPointer();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 3)
        {
            byte dummy = rgbValues[i];
            rgbValues[i] = rgbValues[i + 2];
            rgbValues[i + 2] = dummy;
        }
    }

    bmp.UnlockBits(data);
}
```

[`LockBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/5ey6h79d.aspx) locks the bitmap in memory so that you can access and change the contents directly. If you don't want to have an unsafe context you can create a byte array and use [`Marshal.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy.aspx) to copy the data into it and back to the bitmap after manipulating. Using `LockBits` is the fastest option to manipulate bitmap data (much faster than `GetPixel` or `SetPixel`).

The loop iterator (`i += 3`) depends on the [`PixelFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx) of the bitmap. Here I am assuming it is `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb`. For `Format32bppArgb` it would be `i += 4`.